# Silicon purity and electronic feature density

Tags: electronics

During development of an integrated circuit it is my understanding that you require a silicon purity of 99.99999999%.

Has this always been the case?  In 1971, had the first commercially available integrated circuit (Intel 4004, 10 micron process) reached this level of purity?

How has the purity of silicon for electronic purposes increased as the feature size (gate electrode width) decreased?

I've searched online for multiple days with little success. I'm aware of  Silicon purification processes and really only seeking a definitive data set on the increase of purity during feature reduction; if any at all?

Comment: I'm sure that as the devices got smaller that higher purity silicon was needed. I don't know of a reference for this off-hand.

Comment: I can't give you a source, but I remember something from when I was in college in the 70's. Si and Ge were both used until people figured out that the band gap of Si made it the better choice. The impurities in Si were at a level of parts per billion, and had to be controlled to parts per trillion. Purity was one of the major problems that had to be solved to make transistors and integrated circuits.